# How can I know if the battery is charging or discharging in a WP8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

as the title says, I wonder if anyone knows how can I programmatically know if the battery is charging or discharging in a Windows Phone 8 App. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [DeviceStatus.PowerSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.powersource%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). If `DeviceStatus.PowerSource == PowerSource.External` then the phone is probably charging.

Comment: is it possible to get a event that phone has started charging or discharging, as I connect/disconnect usb ?

Answer (score 1):

try this : DeviceStatus.PowerSource, when the phone is charging, the value is External.